# How can I build CakePHP 3 on Heroku

Tags: php, cakephp, heroku

I want to know how to build CakePHP 3 environment on Heroku.
As easy way as possible.
CakePHP 3 is better, but CakePHP 2 is also good.
Do you know good web site link, or quick build way like Heroku button?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to:
- Add buildpack `heroku/php`,
- connect your heroku with gitRepo
- configure your DNS (heroku link -> your web site)